# Access (.MDB) deployment issue - Windows 7 - Installation with admin user?

Tags: ms-access, deployment, setting

I use microsoft access (.mdb) database for my business software. Recently I have noticed a lot of feedback from users saying that they are unable to open the software after installation.

Basically, I store database in user\appdata\local\myfolder path. Considering the scenario of these users on a windows 7 machine if user tries to install the software (without admin rights) then he has to enter user and password of admin which makes the Inno setup install the database in admin user's local folder instead of logged in user's local data folder.

So after installation, my software cannot locate the database as it is stored in admin user's local data and not the local data folder of logged in user. I use Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData to find localappdata folder for current user in c#.

I don't think there is any other folder where I can store database with read/write permission. Program files folder would not be suitable.

**What could be the best solution for this?**

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I am currently trying with programdata folder using commonappdata constant...it should work i think...

Comment: It does not work as not every user has write permission to programdata folder...:(

Answer (score 0):

I distribute Access databases in a similar way, the best place for it is:

```
C:\User\Username
```

User's should have write properties on their own folder's, if for any reason they do not then the permissions settings should be revised.

So rather than having one copy on the C: drive, there is a copy saved for each individual user.  Even better if user's have a personal shared space which can be accessed from any machine they log on to mapped as a network drive.

Comment: OK. As already mentioned I store my .mdb file in the users\appdata\local folder and if every user installs it then there would be multiple copies which would be pointless in my program's case.

Comment: Now I think I will show a warning if user installs by admin when he is not and if the software cannot find database in his folder, I will ask for a location instead of showing error message